# Binary-Search and Return value

Tags: return-value, binary-search

```
function searchTarget(N, A, X) {
    let start = 0;`=
    let end = A.length - 1;
    // = mid  , < mid , > mid (3 sections)
    // so the target element which needs to be searched lies among these 3 sections
    while (start <= end) {
    let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        if (X === A[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (X < A[mid]) {
            end = mid - 1;
        }
        else {
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(searchTarget(N, A, X));
```

I have a doubt that if we are not returning start and end variable then how this Binary Search function is working.

Answer (score 0):

For binary search, we are indeed only concerned with the resulting position of the target element in the array and do not need to return the additional variables start and end.

the `start` and end `variables` represent the boundaries of the search space. If the target element `X` is equal to the middle element `A[mid]`, the function returns the index of the middle element as it indicates a successful match.

There are four possible situation:

1. If the target element is less than the middle element, the search space is updated to the left half by `end = mid - 1`. This is because the target element in the left half of the current search space.
2. If the target element is greater than the middle element, the search space is updated to the right half by `start = mid + 1`. This is because the target element in the right half of the current search space.
3. If the target element is not found within the search space, the function will reach the `return -1` statement, indicating that the target element is not present in the array.
4. The target element `X` is equal to the middle element `A[mid]`, and we return the position of mid.